# type restrict to sibling value in object

Tags: typescript

I want to limit the type of a value in an object to the value of another value in the same object. Is this possible?

```js
interface A {
    one: string;
    two: string;
    three: string;
    current: one | two | three;  // limit one or two or three above
    //current: string <-- string seems to be too broad for this
}
```

[image]

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+QexAgC5kBnMKUAcwG4c8wB3fUiqkOh3MACygglylGvTzIEAVygDwpQigA+yZvmTK+AiPQC+QA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function to assign the current type

### Update Typescript 5.0

Use generic const

[Plaground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=30&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6pgczAYRAJ3wFMwoAeCBVKRAFQD4AKOAIwCsAuOgGkQgOKkutANoBrIgE84wOgF0AlIgDeAKESJiUAkjUaNAOiOs23dfv6ESULpcFQzGgL6qXqymGqIwRAO4B5dkQAXhR0LFwBa0Y9RAQiLgByZETHRChfOCSWVPMoAAtiBMREiFynXmTEhVVVHwD2AztrEJKUxAB6Du84RCJCOHw6v0C2JqjSVsSczu6wXv78QeGGsebJ0NLE2Z6+gaH60fGrDZKAE22uvaX8IA)

```
function assignCurrent<const T>(obj: T, current: T[keyof T]) {
  return {
    ...obj,
    current: current,
  }
}

const newObj = assignCurrent({
  one: 'a',
  two: 'b',
  three: 'c',
}, 'a')

newObj.current = 'a' // no error
newObj.current = 'b' // no error
newObj.current = 'c' // no error
newObj.current = 'd' // error
```

### Original answer

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=32&pln=15&pc=32#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6pgczAYRAJ3wFMwoAeAFQD4AKOAIwCsAuRCgGkQgONNYoDaAayIBPOMDYBdAJSIA3gChEiYlAJIlKlQDo9DRu2XbuhElFaneUIyoC+ih4ogJUURGCIB3APJNEALwo6Fi4POY0WogIRKwA5MhxtohQXnDx9EnGUAAWxLGIcRBZdsFcrjaFiTKKip6+TDpW5oFVcYgA9B0ecIhEhHD4dd5+jE3hpK1xmZ3dYL39+IPDDWPNk0FF7V09fQND9aPjZhuFACbb3YuDQA)

```
function assignCurrent<T>(obj: T, current: T[keyof T]) {
  return {
    ...obj,
    current: current,
  }
}

const newObj = assignCurrent({
  one: 'a',
  two: 'b',
  three: 'c',
} as const, 'a')

newObj.current = 'a' // no error
newObj.current = 'b' // no error
newObj.current = 'c' // no error
newObj.current = 'd' // error
```

Comment: Although this looks more like a workaround, I am fine with it. Thanks!

Comment: what does as const mean here?

Comment: @AnandShiva The `const` is for making variables readonly.

Comment: i mean why should be make it readonly? is it required for making the code work?

Comment: Yes, Because typescript need to know that the object will not change. If you remove the `const` `newObj.current` will be `string` type.

Answer (score 0):

Create a base interface of the common objects and create required interface from that.

```
interface base {
  one: string;
  two: string;
  three: string;
}

interface A extends base {
  current: keyof base; // limit one or two or three above
  //current: string <-- string seems to be too broad for this
}

const newObject: A = {
  current: "one",
  one: "",
  two: "",
  three: "",
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEZwM4oN4ChnID2IEAXMhmFKAOYDc%20yYA7oeZdSPY2ABZQQyFKrQYBfXLlCRYiFAEFkEAB6QQAEwxpMORggCuUAeHIBrCAE9CMbVjrIA9A%20QAbYAFtgYIiSJQmrH5M-ILIcKiEAG4QjE4GRhAmwpw0yAA8ALQZybQUgu5aYIRoKEXFqFCEcOrIMIT%20fMAYuBK4CMSUyCTMAPKoAFYQCGDkigC8yHgE8cYjyABExBDzADSMS%20Tzqzysm9sEfAJCW2tiDEA)

If don't want to create a new type this is also possible to reference the create interface inside the same interface.

eg

```
interface base {
  one: string;
  two: string;
  three: string;
  current: keyof base;
}

const newObject: base = {
  current: "one",
  one: "",
  two: "",
  three: "",
};
```

Comment: I think I did not phrase it well enough, I mean `current` should be restricted to the value of `one`, `two` or `three`, instead of the key. In your example, it should be restricted to `""` because all three `one`, `two` and `three` are `""`